# jquery -if i uncheck or check the check box the remaining check box values also changed

Tags: jquery

If i click on update button it will display entered value ,checkbox and true/false.if the check box is checked it shows true otherwise false .but here when i uncheck check box the remaining check box values also changed from true to false

**JS/jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){



$("#submit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var val = $("#inputText").val();
    $('#myTable tbody').append("<tr>\n" + "  <td>\n" + val + "  </td>\n"                                + "<td style='align-text:middle'>" + "<input type='checkbox' id='checkbox1' class='alt' name='check' />" + " </td>" + "<td>" + "<input type='text'  id='textbox1' class='textbox1'/><input type='text' class='indexHolder'/>" + "</td>" + "</tr>");
 });
 $("#submit").click(function(d) {
    $('#holder').val(parseInt($('#holder').val())+1);
    $('.textbox1').each(function(){
        $('.textbox1').val($(this).is(':checked'));
        $('.indexHolder').val($('#holder').val());
        $('.alt').change(function() {
            $('.textbox1').val($(this).is(':checked'));

            });
            $(this).click(function() {
            var index=$(this).closest("tr").find(".indexHolder").text(); 
                //alert(index);
                if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {  

                }
            });

        });
});

$("#add").click(function(f) {
    f.preventDefault();

    var val = $("#inputText1").val()
    $('#myTable').append('<tr><td>' + val + '</td></tr>');
});
```

});

If i click on update button it will display entered value ,checkbox and true/false.if the check box is checked it shows true otherwise false .but here when i uncheck check box the remaining check box values also changed from true to false

Comment: The code example is hard to read. Can you re-post with just the check-boxes and include a screen shot?

Comment: ok shall i post in another question

Comment: No, clean this question by using EDIT

Comment: I have edited. should be ok now (if accepted)

Comment: A glaring problem is that all your jQuery code should be inside `$(document).ready()`

Comment: can any one help me

Comment: anyone tell me the solution please

Comment: i resolved this issue

Answer (score 0):

$(document)
                .ready(
                        function() {

```
                        $(".save")
                                .click(
                                        function(e) {
                                            e.preventDefault();
                                            var val = $("#inputText").val();

                                            $("#holder").val(
                                                    parseInt($("#holder")
                                                            .val()) + 1);
                                            var x = $("#holder").val();
                                            var checkbox = "checkbox_" + x;
                                            var textbox = "textbox_" + x;


                                            $('#myTable tbody')
                                                    .append(
                                                            "<tr>\n"
                                                                    + "  <td>\n"
                                                                    + val
                                                                    + "  </td>\n"
                                                                    + "<td style='align-text:middle'>"
                                                                    + "<input type='checkbox' id=" + checkbox + " class='alt' name='check' />"
                                                                    + " </td>"
                                                                    + "<td>"
                                                                    + "<input type='text'  id=" + textbox + " class=" + textbox + "/>"
                                                                    + "</td>"
                                                                    + "</tr>");



                                            $('#textbox_' + x).val($(this).is(':checked'));                                             

                                            $('.alt').click(function() {
                                                var clickedIdVal = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];


                                                if(x == clickedIdVal)   {
                                                    $('#textbox_' + clickedIdVal).val($(this).is(':checked'));
                                                }
                                                else{
                                                    $('#textbox_ '+ clickedIdVal).val($(this).is(':unchecked'));
                                                    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           


                                            });
```